# Python not doing the maths

Tags: python, math, addition

```
import time
import sys
pass1 = False
while pass1 == False:
   bob = int(0)
   hi = int(4)
   password = input("Enter your 4 digit number password: ")
   if bob == 5:
       print("Locked out of phone")
       time.sleep(2)
       sys.exit()
   elif password == "5674":
       print("Correct password")
       pass1 = True
   else:
      hi -= 1
      print("Incorrect password, remaining attempts = ",hi)
      bob = bob + 1
```

I have no idea why it wont just subtract and add 1 to the variables "hi" and "bob."

Comment: You have `bob = 0` inside the loop.

Comment: Why do you write `int(0)` instead of just `0`?

Comment: you reset bob and hi inside the loop. just  put them outside and it will run as expected

Answer (score 2):

`hi` and `bob` are reinitialized each time you enter the loop. Move the initialization outside the loop and you should be OK:

```
bob = 0
hi = 4
while not pass1:
    # loop body...
```

Answer (score 2):

It is actually working, but at the beginning of the loop you reset your variables. It might be worthwhile getting familiar with a tool like `pudb` to figure things like this out.

Here's your code with some extra improvements as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import sys

tries = 0
maxtries = 4

while True:
   tries += 1
   if tries > maxtries:
       print("Locked out of phone")
       time.sleep(2)
       sys.exit()

   password = input("Enter your 4 digit number password: ")
   if password == "5674":
       print("Correct password")
       break
   else:
      print("Incorrect password, remaining attempts = ", maxtries - tries)
```

- moved variable initialisation outside of the loop
- removed the unnecessary `int` calls
- made the loop more pythonic
- gave the variables sensible names

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As @Barmar states, your variable initialization is happening inside the loop. Correct it like so:

```
import time
import sys
pass1 = False
bob = 0
hi = 4
while pass1 == False:
   password = input("Enter your 4 digit number password: ")
   if bob == 5:
       print("Locked out of phone")
       time.sleep(2)
       sys.exit()
   elif password == "5674":
       print("Correct password")
       pass1 = True
   else:
      hi -= 1
      print("Incorrect password, remaining attempts = ",hi)
      bob = bob + 1
```